# Python Loop through excel file and and read each one by one using pandas read_excel function

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to loop through an array that has the excel file name and then use that to read that excel using pandas read_excel. However i am unable to pass the path to read_excel(). Below is how my code looks.

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

Moviedb = []

file_Name = ["/SG_JW_09-02-2020_1900_2009", "/SG_JW_09-02-2020_2010_2015", "/SG_JW_09-02-2020_2016_2017", "/SG_JW_09-02-2020_2018_2020", "/SG_JW_09-02-2020_2018_2020_1", "/SG_JW_09-02-2020_2018_2020_2"]

filecnt = 0
cnt = 0
for filename in file_Name:    
    p = Path("D:/Python scripts/SG Title/SG/JW/03_02_2020" + filename)

    df = pd.read_excel(p)
    filecnt =  filecnt + 1
```

I get the below error when i run this.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fiezj.png)

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Try to pass extension of file as well, i.e. xlsx or whatever file is having.

Answer (score 0):

Path("D:/Python scripts/SG Title/SG/JW/03_02_2020" + filename + ".xlsx")